# Load more feature in Angular2

Tags: json, angular

I am using angular2 and Json. I am fetching all users from Json and showing that in users index page. Now what I want is to show 5 users initially and load more button and clicking on load more button I want to display the next 5 users + previous 5 users and so on. So initially in ngOninit I am doing like this for fetching 5 users:

```
  this.userService.users().subscribe(
  response => {
    if(response['meta'].code == 200) {
      this.users = response['data'];
      this.users = this.users.slice(0, 5);
    }else{
      console.log(response['meta'].message)
    }
  },
  err => {
    console.log('err:', err);
  }
);
```

This is the load more button in view:

```
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click) = "loadMore()">Load More..</a>
```

Now I wrote method:

```
 loadMore(){
  alert("hello");
  // here I am not getting how to fetch the next 5 records + previous records and so on.
 }
```

So,Could anyone please help me?

Comment: So do you need to get the information again by sending to the UserService or are they all loaded response['data'].

Comment: All the users are coming in response['data'].

Answer (score 0):

You can store all users and just display a part (slice) of it.
Your loadMore method just creates this new slice.

```
origUsers = response['data'];
i = 5;
this.users = origUsers.slice(0, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

because you should not proceed like this.

first, your service should store all the users. Then, you should return a slice of your users on demand, while saving the page. It should give something like this :

```js
users : any[] = [];
offset : number = 0;

getUsers() {
  // get your JSON users, store them in users
}

getPaginatedUsers() {
  let tmp = this.users.slice(this.offset, this.offset + 5);
  this.offset += 5;
  return tmp;
}

// In your component

this.userService.getUsers(); // Do this in the on init function
this.users = this.userService.getPaginatedUsers();
loadMore() {
  this.users.push(...this.userService.getPaginatedUsers);
}

// your HTML
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click) = "loadMore()">Load More..</a>
```

Comment: this.users = this.userService.getPaginatedUsers();
whenever I am using this I am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null.

Comment: Did you load your users as I wrote ? Because it seems you did not

Comment: Yes Sorry for that. now I am not getting any error but I am not getting the output as well while clicking on loadMore button.

Comment: I have edited my answer, add the loadMore function in your component

Comment: Thanks but in this method getPaginatedUsers() after return we can't increase offset value it is throwing unreachable code. and after adding loadMore method and clicking on that the row is increasing by 1 but the users details are not coming.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't test my code, and I see my mistake. That's dumb from me, please see the edited answer.